# how to set a custom Eastern DateTime in Snowplow Stream Collector or Is there any method or feature available in the Snowplow/Snowplow Web package?

Tags: dbt, snowplow

I am utilizing a snowplow to track records, but since the records are stored in UTC timestamp, I must establish a custom timestamp. is there any way iavailable to change the custome timestamp

Or, I am using the Snowplow/Snowplow Web dbt package. Is there any method or feature available in the Snowplow/Snowplow Web package?